# How to highlight whole row and column under cursor in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I need to work with large table. Something like in this illustation image will be helpfull for better orientation:

[image]

Is there some settings which makes this possible?

Comment: Currently, it is not implemented. There's a feature request for this for LibreOffice at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33201

Comment: OMG, this bug is open since 2011 ^^

Answer (score 13):

Not exactly as requested, but <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> selects current row / column respectively (at least in LibreOffice Calc - i didn't test it with OpenOffice!). To unselect, just move the selection using the cursor keys.

Comment: Yes this works in OpenOffice too. Good tip, thanks.

Comment: Clarification: Shift-Space *selects* the entire Row.  Ctrl-Shift-Space *selects* the entire Column.  An effect of selecting a row/column is that that row/column is also highlighted.  Cannot just highlight both row and column as the pic indicates, because it is actually a selection, which would instead select the entire table.  However, one *could* format cells with a background color.  First select a row or column, then fill with background color, then repeat with the other.  More labor intensive, but also pervasive.

Comment: As of 4th of Febuary, 2020 in LibreOffice 6.3.4.2, Ctrl-Shift-Space selects all cells in the sheet. Ctrl-Space selects the entire column and Shift-Space selects the entire row.