# How to highlight the current row and column like a crosshair in Libreoffice?

Tags: gui, libreoffice-calc, setup, highlighting, usability

How can I highlight the current row and column like a crosshair in Libreoffice as guide for the eye?

[image: crosshair in Libreoffice]

There seems to be an open [feature request from 2011](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33201) and a very similar question for [openoffice](https://superuser.com/questions/899479/how-to-highlight-whole-row-and-column-under-cursor-in-openoffice-calc.)  - but nothing I can find on libreoffice and supported at the moment. How can I get LibreOffice to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to highlight whole row and column under cursor in OpenOffice Calc?](https://superuser.com/questions/899479/how-to-highlight-whole-row-and-column-under-cursor-in-openoffice-calc), which links to the original ticket (2011) to implement this feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lupp has recently created an example spreadsheet that uses macros for this behavior.  It's posted at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43531#p431848.

However, he remarks [at AskLO](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/137779/how-can-calc-be-set-to-highlight-the-row-of-the-active-cell/?answer=137918#post-id-137918) that:

> It's a questionable approach to use "macros" for the purpose.  The solution is only applicable to sheets that do not use hard (direct) cell formatting... Not actually recommended!

The only good solution would be if it could be implemented in LibreOffice.  But as you may have read in the bug report:

> Talking to one of the experienced developers...it's no trivial task. It might never be implemented.

As mentioned in my answer to that same question on AskLO, a practical solution is to use conditional formatting to add color to odd or even rows.

**EDIT**:

To reproduce Lupp's example starting from scratch, first go to *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic.*  Find the .ods document, press *New* to create a new module, and put the following code in the module.

```vb
Global focusCellAddressGl As String, columnWithFocusCellGl As Long, rowWithFocusCellGl As Long

Function focusCell(Optional pCtrl) As Object
REM Concept by "uros", "Villeroy"
REM Responsible for this variant: Wolfgang Jäger
REM 2017-09-28 V0
On Error Goto eExit
If IsMissing(pCtrl) Then pCtrl = ThisComponent.CurrentController
If  NOT pCtrl.SupportsService("com.sun.star.sheet.SpreadsheetView") Then Exit Function
    Dim theSheet As Object, fC As Object, sheetNum As Long, sInfo As String, sInfoDelim As String 
    Dim vD, vDSplit, sInfoSplit
vD             = pCtrl.ViewData
vDSplit        = Split(vD, ";")
theSheet       = pCtrl.ActiveSheet's(sheetNum)
sheetNum       = theSheet.RangeAddress.Sheet
sInfo          = vDSplit(sheetNum + 3)
REM For CellAddress.Row >= 8192 the "+" is used as the subdelimiter in ViewData. WHY?
If InStr(sInfo, "+")>0 Then 
    sInfoDelim = "+"
Else
    sInfoDelim = "/"
End If
sInfoSplit     = Split(sInfo, sInfoDelim)
fC             = theSheet.GetCellByPosition(sInfoSplit(0), sInfoSplit(1))
focusCell      = fC
eExit:
End Function 

Function focusCellAddress(Optional pDummy)
On Error Goto eExit
If focusCellAddressGl="" Then onSelectionChanged(NULL)
focusCellAddress=focusCellAddressGl
eExit:
End Function

Function columnWithFocusCell(Optional pDummy)
On Error Goto eExit
If columnWithFocuscellGl=0 Then onSelectionChanged(NULL)
columnWithFocusCell=columnWithFocusCellGl
eExit:
End Function

Function rowWithFocusCell(Optional pDummy)
On Error Goto eExit
If rowWithFocuscellGl=0 Then onSelectionChanged(NULL)
rowWithFocusCell=rowWithFocusCellGl
eExit:
End Function

Sub onSelectionChanged(pEvent)
On Error Goto eExit
tFC=focusCell()
focusCellAddressGl=Split(tFC.AbsoluteName,".")(1)
With tFC.CellAddress
columnWithFocusCellGl=.Column+1
rowWithfocusCellGl=.Row+1
End With
specCell=tFC.Spreadsheet.GetCellByPosition(0,0)
specCell.String = tFC.AbsoluteName
eExit:
End Sub
```

Now, right-click on the tab of the current sheet and choose *Sheet Events*.  Assign `onSelectionChanged` to the "Selection changed" event.

Also, create style `cfFocusCross` with a background color.

Finally, go to *Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage -> Add.*

- Formula is `OR(ROW(A1)=ROWWITHFOCUSCELL();COLUMN(A1)=COLUMNWITHFOCUSCELL())+N($A$1)*0`
- Apply style `cfFocusCross`
- Range `A1:Z100`

[image: spreadsheet with row and column highlighted]

Comment: I suggest to add the complete code here, because users will probably still visit  the sx page when the forum already moved, switched the software or the URL is dead.

Comment: @Jonas Stein: OK, code has been added along with instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality is built-in in LibreOffice since version 24.2.

The option can be enabled through:
Tools ▸ Options ▸ LibreOffice Calc ▸ View, or through the menu entry View ▸ Column/Row Highlighting.

[Info in Release notes for Libreoffice 24.2](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/24.2#Column/Row_Highlighting_for_Active_Cell)